# How to compare commits and send notification about the commit

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, rest, bitbucket

Suppose there are three branches namely feature, release and develop. There's a merge from feature to develop and feature to release. Since the commit Id is different it is considered as a difference between develop and release but in reality both have the changes. So my task is here is to send mail to all those people who had made changes in release but not in develop for several repositories. How do I get the difference and the detail of author who made the difference.

I have written a Java spring boot code using which the compare option of stash is called using rest API but that option yields incorrect data as I mentioned earlier. So how do I compare it and get exact correct results.

Comment: If  branch `X` should be merged in 2 different branches, you could check if each of the target branches already has it merged with `git branch --contains=X` or something along those lines.

Comment: Just ignore the commits with the default merge message? This should leave you with the actual commits from which you can exclude changes that are in develop

Comment: Even if using the git contains command I find that a certain changes have not been merged, how do I find that who in particular made which changes? Only if I have that clear idea I can send an notification right?

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of author emails who contributed to a branch, you can use the following command:

```
git log --pretty='format:%ae' upstream..feature
```

Apply the usual `sort -u` or `sort | uniq` pattern to get only unique emails (`awk '!seen[$0]++'` works too).